# Using appcompat-v7 to apply Material Theme to API Version 19 and Below

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library

I recently downloaded the Android Lollipop SDK and i've updated all my dependencies, fixed my build paths and imported the following support libraries without issue:

android-support-v7-appcompat
android-support-v7-gridlayout
android-support-v7-mediarouter
android-support-v7-palette

My app uses Bluetooth low energy, so my minSDK version is 18 and targetSDK is the latest; 21.

My issues come when I try to use the following xml to apply the Material Theme (using the appcompat-v7):

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_green_A200</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <!-- <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppBaseActionBar</item> -->
</style>

<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
```

When I tried running this, I got the following error:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'colorAccent' with value '@color/material_green_A200')

After a bit of Googling I come across this github repository updated 3 days ago: gist.github.com/eyecatchup/b5e564cfe11619cc3999

There, most Material design colors are defined, so I just copied it to my theme's color.xml.

I then get the following error despite the fact that that line is in the xml:

Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'bright_foreground_material_light' with value '@color/black').

Anyway I delete that particular line and successfully install the app on my phone. However, the theme is still Holo and not Material.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) very clearly say I can use the Material theme in versions lower than 5.0, and I followed the instructions listed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) about maintaining compatibility.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Add color in resource by name "material_green_A200"...

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was only applying the theme to my custom theme in my values folder, while the values-v11 and values-v14 theme xml remained unchanged.

That fixed, I got the material theme running by pretty much updating my activities to extend ActionBarActivity and my fragment managers to `getSupportFragmentManager()` managers as opposed to `getFragmentManager()`.

If you happen to use a Navigation Drawer, in your getActionBar, when setting the adapter for your ListView, you will need to cast the ActionBar to a SupportActionBar like this:

```
private ActionBar getSupportActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}
```

and set the adapter as you usually would like this:

```
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(getSupportActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(),
            R.layout.fragment_navigationdrawer_textview,
            android.R.id.text1, drawerOptions));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
```

Hope that helps anyone with the same issues I had. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

you have to create new project ofter then Id's are automatically generate appcompat_v7 library often then right click on your old error project click on property then click android and add appcompat_v7 library in your project.

Comment: I've already added the appcompat_v7 library to my project. My project currently has no errors and it runs fine, the only problem is the theme is still Holo despite using the appcompat_v7 Material Theme.